# Rewriting sequental code for parallel execution

Tags: parallel-processing, refactoring, lisp, common-lisp

What is best idiomatic approach to rewrite common lisp sequential code for parallel execution?

There is some good libraries, like lparallel, helping with simple cases. For example, if we had some mapcar on long list, we can replace it with lparallel:mapcar, and it'll do the job in most cases. Now I have some loop call, taking result of some remote JSON API and nconcing it into list:

```
(loop :for offset :from 0 :by 100
           :for result = (get-remote-data offset) 
           :until (null result) :nconc result)
```

How replace it, to call `get-remote-data` in parallel without needs to change `get-remote-data` itself? Is there any standard and idiomatic ways? Any good read on this topic also will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I have used `chanl` for such a use case to set up a message queue.  I
started *n* worker threads that made the remote calls and sent it to
the queue.  An aggregator got the results from the queue and
concatenated them.

If order is important, this might not be right.  You could perhaps
pre-define a result array that is filled in at the defined separate
offsets by the workers.

*EDIT:* In order to get an unknown number of pages, you could use an
atomic offset counter and an atomic flag.  The worker threads (from a
fixed pool) then check the flag, get the next offset from the counter,
make the remote call, finally either send the result to the queue or,
if the result is empty, flip the flag off.  If the flag is flipped off
any worker thread checking it shuts itself down.  When the worker
thread pool is empty, you are finished.

Comment: For this particular case order isn't important, but I need to call get-remote-data until it returns empty list (as you may see), so how can I do it with chanl? I don't know how many calls enaugh to get all data.

Comment: The part where you say until it returns an empty list seems to contradict order is not important. You may also would like to check lparallel and cl-async, which has a(synchronous)let

Comment: @PuercoPop, I ment,that it's not really important for me in what order I'll get all responses NCONC-ed. I don't think it contradicts. I'll take a look at cl-async, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the following using lparallel:

```
(defun get-datum (n)
     (sleep (random 2))
     (if (> n 1000)
         ()
         (list n)))

(defun get-data ()
  (let ((channel (lparallel:make-channel))
        results)
    (flet ((collect (item)
             (setq results (append item results))))

      ;; Ask lparallel to schedule the first 8 requests
      (loop for i from 0 to 70 by 10
            do (lparallel:submit-task channel #'get-datum i))

      ;; Schedule an additional request each time one returns
      ;; until we get a null result
      (loop for i from 80 by 10
            for result = (lparallel:receive-result channel)
            while result
            do (lparallel:submit-task channel #'get-datum i)
            (collect result))

      ;; wait for all outstanding requests
      (loop repeat 7
            do (collect (lparallel:receive-result channel)))

      results)))
```